# How to hide web service input parameters from browser

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have simple rest web services, with different forms of input parameters. Query Parameters, Form Parameters& Multi part Parameters.

when i open Network and fire a web service call i can see all the parameters being passed. I don't want anybody to see those parameters.
Any ideas how i can hide those from browser?

Comment: Can you please tell me more about how i can encrypt and decrypt at the webs ervice

Comment: No currently it is http only

Comment: ok thanks .....but is there any way to encrypt with http using any mechanism

Comment: if it is https, do i need to do anything or it will automatically encrypt?

Comment: It will go automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

Buy a SSL certificate for your domain, install it on the webserver.. and let the traffic go trough **HTTPS** :)

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the qucik response :)